# Flex not compiling Lexical Analyser - error with macro

Tags: c, macros, flex-lexer

I am having a problem with my lexical analyser written in flex. When I try to compile it there is no exe file created and I get a lot of errors. The following is the flex file:

```
%{
#ifdef PRINT
#define TOKEN(t) printf("Token: " #t "\n");
#else
#define TOKEN(t) return(t);
#endif
%}

delim       [ \t\n]
ws          {delim}+
digit       [0-9]
id          {character}({character}|{digit})*
number      {digit}+
character   [A-Za-z]
%%
{ws}            ; /* Do Nothing */


":"             TOKEN(COLON);
";"             TOKEN(SEMICOLON);
","             TOKEN(COMMA);
"("             TOKEN(BRA);
")"             TOKEN(CKET);
"."             TOKEN(DOT);
"'"             TOKEN(APOS);

"="             TOKEN(EQUALS);
"<"             TOKEN(LESSTHAN);
">"             TOKEN(GREATERTHAN);

"+"             TOKEN(PLUS);
"-"             TOKEN(SUBTRACT);
"*"             TOKEN(MULTIPLY);
"/"             TOKEN(DIVIDE);

{id}            TOKEN(ID);

{number}        TOKEN(NUMBER);

'{character}'   TOKEN(CHARACTER_CONSTANT);

%%
```

These are the errors I receive:

```
spl.l: In function 'yylex':

spl.l:19:7: error: 'COLON' undeclared (first use in this function)
 ":"    TOKEN(COLON);
       ^

spl.l:5:25: note: in definition of macro 'TOKEN'
 #define TOKEN(t) return(t);
                         ^

spl.l:19:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 ":"    TOKEN(COLON);
       ^

spl.l:5:25: note: in definition of macro 'TOKEN'
 #define TOKEN(t) return(t);
                         ^

spl.l:20:7: error: 'SEMICOLON' undeclared (first use in this function)
 ";"    TOKEN(SEMICOLON);
       ^

spl.l:5:25: note: in definition of macro 'TOKEN'
 #define TOKEN(t) return(t);
```

And the commands I am using to compile are:

```
flex a.l
gcc -o newlex.exe lex.yy.c -lfl
```

Can anyone see where I may be going wrong?

Comment: BTW you shouldn't need a ";" in your macro as you're calling it with one already

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the tokens first. The definitions (i.e. ids) for `COLON`, `SEMICOLON`, etc. pp. are not generated by flex. You could define it in an enum at the top of your lexer file:

```
%{
#ifdef PRINT
#define TOKEN(t) printf("Token: " #t "\n");
#else
#define TOKEN(t) return(t);
#endif  

enum { COLON = 257, SEMICOLON, COMMA, BRA, CKET, DOT, APOS, EQUALS,
       LESSTHAN, GREATERTHAN, PLUS, SUBTRACT, MULTIPLY, DIVIDE,
       ID, NUMBER, CHARACTER_CONSTANT };
%}
```

I suggest ids > 257 here to be able to also directly return ascii character codes from the lexer for further processing.
Usually, however, the token names are also used in a parser file for yacc/bison, which generates a header file (default name is `y.tab.h`) for inclusion in your lexer, which contains generated ids for those tokens which also match the parser functions.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense now!